# Inconsistent in uploading a file using webclient (C#)

Tags: c#

I am uploading a file(Zip with the size 100MB) using WebClient but it works fine some times, Fail some times

Here is My Code Please let me know your Views and What need to be done to Make it Consistent

```
public bool UploadFirmware(string srcPath, string destPath)
    {
        bool status = false;
        List<Unisys.sPar.FirmwareInfo> orgFwList = new List<Unisys.sPar.FirmwareInfo>();
        List<Unisys.sPar.FirmwareInfo> upFwList = new List<Unisys.sPar.FirmwareInfo>();
        try
        {
            orgFwList = EnumerateFirmware();
            Uri fwuri = new Uri(destPath);
            string myStringWebResource = null;
            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            myStringWebResource = fwuri.ToString();
            myWebClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            myWebClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/zip";
            bool gExecuteOnce = true;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
            myWebClient.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(myWebClientUploadloadFileCompleted);
            myWebClient.UploadFileAsync(new System.Uri(myStringWebResource), "POST", srcPath);//upload method 
            while (myWebClient.IsBusy)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                if (gExecuteOnce == true)
                {
                    SPARTestToolInit.logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Info, "Please Wait Uploading firmware.....");
                    gExecuteOnce = false;
                }

            }
            upFwList = EnumerateFirmware();
            if (upFwList.Count == orgFwList.Count + 1)
            {
                status = true;
                SPARTestToolInit.logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Info, "Firmware Uploaded sucessfuly .....");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status = false;
            SPARTestToolInit.logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Error, "Unable to upload firmware due to " + ex.ToString());
        }

        return status;
    }
```

Comment: What's the exception when it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     1. don't pool if webclient busy, you have a callback   myWebClientUploadloadFileCompleted
     2. set successfull status in you completed callback not in your method

     static ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent(false);


          public bool UploadFirmware(string srcPath, string destPath)
                {
                    bool status = false;
                    List<Unisys.sPar.FirmwareInfo> orgFwList = new List<Unisys.sPar.FirmwareInfo>();
                    List<Unisys.sPar.FirmwareInfo> upFwList = new List<Unisys.sPar.FirmwareInfo>();
                    try
                    {
                        orgFwList = EnumerateFirmware();
                        Uri fwuri = new Uri(destPath);
                        string myStringWebResource = null;
                        WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
                        myStringWebResource = fwuri.ToString();
                        myWebClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                        myWebClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
                        myWebClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/zip";
                        bool gExecuteOnce = true;
                        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
                        myWebClient.UploadFileCompleted += new UploadFileCompletedEventHandler(myWebClientUploadloadFileCompleted);
                        myWebClient.UploadFileAsync(new System.Uri(myStringWebResource), "POST", srcPath);//upload method 

                      done.WaitOne();//wait signal from completed callback

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        status = false;
                        SPARTestToolInit.logger.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Error, "Unable to upload firmware due to " + ex.ToString());
                    }

                    return status;
                }


static void client_UploadFileCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        done.Set();
    }

static void client_UploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //set your progress log
    }
```